# Can not compare two ISO format dates using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am comparing two dates using javascript but always its returning the wrong result. I am explaining my code below.

```
dateLessThan(from: string, to: string) {
    console.log(from,to);
    var d1 = new Date(from);
    var d2 = new Date(to);
    console.log('converted time',d1,d2);
    if (from > to) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}
```

here in my second console message I am getting `converted time Fri Jan 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` but its always returns true. Here I need to compare both dates.

Comment: how about `d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()`?

Comment: @Surely: I did as per you. Here my converted input `Fri Jan 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` but it returns true.

Comment: You are comparing strings but haven't shown what the strings are. What is *to* and *from*? You say they are "ISO format dates" but timestamps like 2020-01-24 are parsed as UTC, so the local timestamp should have a time component equal to the offset (i.e. Fri Jan 24 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick-and-dirty solution. Please note that this will not work if you attempt to compare two dates in two different timezones. It assumes that each date is in the same timezone.

```js
function dateLessThan(from, to) {
    //console.log(from,to);
    var d1 = new Date(from);
    var d2 = new Date(to);
    //console.log('converted time',d1,d2);
    /* This is your code.
    if (from > to) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    */
    
    // Here is the easy way to do it with the strings.
    return d1.toISOString() < d2.toISOString();
}

console.log('Should be true: ' + dateLessThan('2011-01-01', '2013-01-01'));
console.log('Should be false: ' + dateLessThan('2014-01-01', '2013-01-01'));
```

Comment: The OP has not provided the format of the strings, you're just guessing. Given the output strings from `console.log('converted time',d1,d2);` they are not YYYY-MM-DD or they'd be parsed as UTC and have a time of 05:30:00 matching the offset.

Comment: Yes, I had to assume. If the OP had updated the question with proper test case scenarios, then I would update my response. I also left a note that it only worked with the cases that I gave and assumed that timezone differences were not the case, as I had not tested for those values.